# Parametric adjunctions form cowedges

Tags: category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$ A few premises to my question:

- Since I am trying to formalise the following theorem in a proof assistant, I *need* to complete the fine details of it, no handwaving of sorts.
- The result in itself is well-known and elementary, but there is something I can't figure out. It's not that I can't prove it, it's that I can't prove it "fully equationally", so to speak.

---

**Theorem.** Let $L_c\dashv R_c$ be a parametric adjunction, by which I mean that $L : C\times D \to E$, $R : C^{op}\times E \to D$ are two functors such that for every $c\in C$, $L_c = L(c,-)$ has $R_c = R(c,-)$ as right adjoint. Then the counit of $L_c\dashv R_c$, i.e. the natural transformation $\epsilon^c : L_cR_c\Rightarrow 1_E$, is a cowedge in $c$.

While I can think of at least three different arguments leading to this result, the line of reasoning that is most suited to be given to agda is the following: consider the dinaturality square
$$ \begin{CD}
L_cR_{c'} @>L_f * R_{c'}>> L_{c'}R_{c'} \\ 
@VL_c * R_fVV @VV\epsilon^{c'}V \\
L_cR_c @>>\epsilon_c> 1
\end{CD}$$
for a given $f : c\to c'$, whose components are natural transformations. Now, by the bijection between 2-cells $L_cR_{c'}\to 1$ and 2-cells $R_{c'}\to R_c$ given by "mating" says that this square commutes if and only if the adjoints of $\epsilon^c\circ (L_c * R_f)$ and of $\epsilon^{c'}\circ (L_f * R_{c'})$ are the same arrow, namely $R_f : R_{c'}\Rightarrow R_c$, which -when one unwinds the definition- means that when the square is whiskered on the left with $R_{c'}$ and its north-west side precomposed with the suitable component of $\eta^c$, it stays commutative and its diagonal is $R_f$:

[image]

By completing the upper part of the diagram, we get

[image]

so $\epsilon^c \circ R_c * L_f$ mates to $R_f$, using one of the zig-zag identities of the adjunction $L_c\dashv R_c$.

As for the left part of the diagram, it doesn't seem that there is a way to reduce $((R_c * L_f)\circ \eta^c) * R_{c'}$ without using the fact that $\eta^c$ is a wedge:

[image]

From which, using a triangle identity for $\eta^{c'}, \epsilon^{c'}$, one easily concludes that also the other pair of arrows mate to $R_f$.

But this is very unsatisfying:

- I don't think I need to know in advance that $\eta$ is a wedge, in order to prove that $\epsilon$ is a cowedge; mostly because the most you can get from this line of reasoning is that $\eta$ is a wedge if and only if $\epsilon$ is a cowedge, whereas by dualizing the argument, however you prove one result you prove the other, independently. So, there must be another way to conclude this proof.
- ...or is there something I am missing? The proof is a classic exercise in Mac Lane, and another way to argue -which to a human eye is completely equivalent to this, uses the hom-bijection. But...
- ...let me stress that, since I am trying to formalize this result in a proof assistant, whatever proof I find has to be *fully equational* and *with no handwaving*.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by theorem $\text{A}^{op}$. Also it seems like you're asking for a better way to prove this, which I'm not sure is appropriate for this site

Comment: Well, I am asking (1) whether you see a flaw in my reasoning; (2) if there is an alternative way to prove this statement; (3) considering I am pretty sure the proof of this statement does not rely on the proof of its opposite, what went wrong? I agree question (3) is more suited for another stackexchange site, but I am trying to prove this statement in agda-categories, so I thought the discussion was more proof-assistant related than CT-related. Was I wrong? Should I repost on MO/MSE?

Comment: [This discussion](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/a/87/75) sets precedent for questions not explicitly related to proof assistants to be off topic, so yes, I think it would be better suited for MSE/MO. An exception (for example) would be if you were explicitly asking how to formalize some part of your argument in (say) agda, or how best to use agda-categories for your proof. I'd henceforth argue that all (1), (2), and (3) are off topic here.

Comment: @fosco: As Couchy says, so far this question has nothing to do with proof assistants. It's purely a category-theoretic question, which makes it relevant to MathOverflow and/or Math SE. Once you've resolved the math, you're more than welcome to ask here about any points of formalization.

Comment: Ok, thanks! -------

Comment: And don't forget to submit PRs of re-usable things to agda-categories!

Comment: That's exactly why I am working on this. You'll hear back from me soon, I hope

Comment: In the statement of the theorem, do you include that $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom(L(c,x),y) ≅ \Hom(x,R(c,y))$ is natural *in $c$* as well as in $x$ and $y$? Because it's natural in $c$ iff one of the unit or counit is a wedge/cowedge.

Comment: Also are ends not available in agda?

Comment: @Dabouliplop I know! It is natural in all possible variables. Did my definition of $L,R$ miss that property? And, ends at the moment are not available, besides the bare definition. They will be soon, hopefully!

Comment: At least in the statement of the theorem. And you will need to use it somewhere in the proof but I don't see it now. Maybe I missed it.

Comment: @JacquesCarette The code (a stub: some proof terms in `MorphismReasoning`'s are missing) is available for everyone to see here https://github.com/agda/agda-categories/pull/360 comments are welcome!

Comment: @fosco I'll be getting to those PRs this week. Couple of deadlines to make sure I meet first.

Answer (score 1):

Using the naturality of $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom(u,R(c,x)) → \Hom(L(c,u),x)$ in $c$, we get the commutativity of the following diagram.

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Hom(R(c,x),R(c,x)) @>>> \Hom(L(c,R(c,x)),x)\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\Hom(R(c',x),R(c,x)) @>>> \Hom(L(c,R(c',x)),x)\\
@AAA @AAA\\
\Hom(R(c',x),R(c',x))@>>> \Hom(L(c',R(c',x)),x)
\end{CD}$

However, I have the impression that you use the unit-counit definition of adjunctions (in which case I don't see what to do because the wedge thing is the formulation of "naturality in $c$" in that context). I cannot post the diagram as a comment because of the @ characters.

Comment: Yes, this is the proof I had in mind, and I believe the above argument (showing that both sides of the square mate to the same $R_f : R_{c'}\to R_c$) is equivalent, but it works better in agda because it is more formal . Am I wrong, am I using weaker assumptions? (I am trying to let agda deduce naturality from my definition now. Will tell you if I win.)

Comment: @fosco Ok, please tell me! But the thing I would like to know is how do you formulate "naturality in $c$" as an hypothesis? Are you using the hom-set definition of adjunction or the unit-counit?

Comment: The unit-counit; agda-categories has both formulations, but working with hom-bijections is less straightforward and a direct way to setoid hell!

Comment: @fosco Ok but then how do you include in the statement of the theorem the hypothesis of naturality in $c$? It needs to be somewhere. Otherwise there are counter-examples. Example: let $C$ be the "walking idempotent", $\newcommand{\Ab}{\mathbf{Ab}}L : C×\Ab→\Ab$ selecting the identity idempotent and $R : C×\Ab→\Ab$ selecting the zero idempotent. Then $L_c$ and $R_c$ are both the identity for the unique $c ∈ C$ but the counit is not a cowedge.

Comment: Meanwhile I managed to prove the initial result with a preliminary `nat` lemma! Hooray! Once that hole has been closed -maybe modifying the definition a little bit- I think I am satisfied.

Comment: What was the saying? "I thought I knew math, until I tried to formalize it" :-)

Comment: Bravo! I still don't know how the hypothesis of naturality in $c$ is formalized but anyway...

Comment: It seems to be equivalent to the wedge condition fo $\eta$, which in hindsight was to be expected; but now I don't know hw to formalize the result any more. Should I *postulate* naturality in $c$? Should I encode it in the definition of the record for parametric adjunctions? At this point I don't realy know if this is a question for MSE or for proof-assistants... uff!

Comment: @fosco I would say that if adjunctions are encoded as a unit-counit pair, then it is natural that the wedge/cowedge condition should be part of the definition of a "parametric adjunction" instead of the "naturality in $c$" which is the analogue on the hom-sets side. (And there might be a theorem saying that we only need to check one of the two.) I hope the situation with proof assistants will improve one day...

Comment: The code is available for everyone to see here https://github.com/agda/agda-categories/pull/360

Comment: Nice, thanks for letting me know. I was wondering if it was available.