# Parametric adjunctions induce cowedges, a real proof

Tags: category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$ Since I am trying to formalise the following theorem in a proof assistant, I *need* to complete the fine details of it, no handwaving of sorts.

**Theorem.** Let $L_c\dashv R_c$ be a parametric adjunction, by which I mean that $L : C\times D \to E$, $R : C^{op}\times E \to D$ are two functors such that for every $c\in C$, $L_c = L(c,-)$ has $R_c = R(c,-)$ as right adjoint. Then the counit of $L_c\dashv R_c$, i.e. the natural transformation $\epsilon^c : L_cR_c\Rightarrow 1$, is a cowedge in $c$.

While I can think of at least three different arguments leading to this result, the line of reasoning that is most suited to be given to agda is the following: consider the dinaturality square
$$ \begin{CD}
L_cR_{c'} @>L_f * R_{c'}>> L_{c'}R_{c'} \\ 
@VL_c * R_fVV @VV\epsilon^{c'}V \\
L_cR_c @>>\epsilon_c> 1
\end{CD}$$
for a given $f : c\to c'$, whose components are natural transformations. Now, by the bijection between 2-cells $L_cR_{c'}\to 1$ and 2-cells $R_{c'}\to R_c$ given by "mating" this square commutes if and only if the adjoints of $\epsilon^c\circ (L_c * R_f)$ and of $\epsilon^{c'}\circ (L_f * R_{c'})$ are the same arrow, namely $R_f : R_{c'}\Rightarrow R_c$, which -when one unwinds the definition- means that when the square is whiskered on the left with $R_{c'}$ and its north-west side precomposed with the suitable component of $\eta^c$, it stays commutative and its diagonal is $R_f$:
[image]

By completing the upper part of the diagram, we get
[image]

so $\epsilon^c \circ R_c * L_f$ mates to $R_f$. As for the left part of the diagram, it doesn't seem that there is a way to reduce $((R_c * L_f)\circ \eta^c) * R_{c'}$ without using the fact that $\eta^c$ is a wedge:
[image]

From which, using a triangle identity for $\eta^{c'}, \epsilon^{c'}$, one easily concludes that also the other pair of arrows mate to $R_f$.

But this is very unsatisfying, because to prove theorem A I need to have theorem $A^{op}$ already there; and if theorem $A^{op}$ doesn't need theorem $A$ to be proved, why theorem $A$ does?

Comment: @fosco Sorry, I did not realize you had already reposted here before migrating, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4580923/parametric-adjunctions-form-cowedges
Please delete question